# How many HTTP verbs are there?

Tags: http, methods, request, protocols

I count 9 [HTTP request methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods) (aka verbs):

```
GET
HEAD
POST
PUT
DELETE
CONNECT
OPTIONS
TRACE
PATCH
```

The above from:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods

Is that it? will this ever change?

Comment: Note:  I know that formally these are "HTTP request methods" but I also see them referred to as "verbs", as the link above describes.

Comment: Technically, anything can happen. There seems to be some malware which apparently tries to transmit data via fabricated "verbs" - in one case, the verb looks like a very long (slightly obfuscated) base64 string. Now, such a thing is not HTTP as defined in any RFC. But it might pop up in your network traces.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

## Registry

The HTTP 1.1 spec defines an [Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP) Method Registry](http://www.iana.org/assignments/http-methods/http-methods.xhtml). As of 2017-01, shows 39 entries:

- ACL
- BASELINE-CONTROL
- BIND
- CHECKIN
- CHECKOUT
- CONNECT
- COPY
- DELETE
- GET
- HEAD
- LABEL
- LINK
- LOCK
- MERGE
- MKACTIVITY
- MKCALENDAR
- MKCOL
- MKREDIRECTREF
- MKWORKSPACE
- MOVE
- OPTIONS
- ORDERPATCH
- PATCH
- POST
- PRI
- PROPFIND
- PROPPATCH
- PUT
- REBIND
- REPORT
- SEARCH
- TRACE
- UNBIND
- UNCHECKOUT
- UNLINK
- UNLOCK
- UPDATE
- UPDATEREDIRECTREF
- VERSION-CONTROL

## HTTP 1.0

[HTTP](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) 1.0 defined three methods (“verbs”):

- **GET**
  … retrieve whatever information … is identified by the Request-URI…
- **POST**
  … to request that the destination server accept
  the entity enclosed in the request as a new subordinate of the
  resource identified by the Request-URI in the Request-Line… Posting a message to a bulletin board, newsgroup, mailing list … Providing a block of data … Extending a database through an append operation …
- **HEAD**
  … identical to GET except that the server MUST NOT
  return a message-body in the response … for obtaining metainformation about the entity implied by the request without transferring the entity-body itself…

## HTTP 1.1

HTTP 1.1 is officially defined in [RFC 2068](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2068). This spec added five more methods.

- **OPTIONS**
  …a request for information about the
  communication options available on the request/response chain… determine the options and/or requirements associated with a resource,
  or the capabilities of a server, without implying a resource action
  or initiating a resource retrieval
- **PUT**
  …requests that the enclosed entity be stored under the
  supplied Request-URI. If … already
  existing resource, the enclosed entity SHOULD be considered as a
  modified version of the one residing on the origin server…
- **DELETE**
  …delete the resource
  identified by the Request-URI…
- **TRACE**
  …loop-
  back of the request message…
- **CONNECT**
  …for use with a proxy that can dynamically switch to being a tunnel (e.g. SSL tunneling…

## HTTP Extensions

Other protocols extend HTTP to define additional methods/verbs.

- [PATCH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patch_verb)
- Applies partial modifications to a resource
- Defined by [RFC 5789](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789)
- [WebDAV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebDAV) specifies seven more methods:

  - PROPFIND
  - PROPPATCH
  - MKCOL
  - COPY
  - MOVE
  - LOCK
  - UNLOCK

## HTTP/2

[HTTP/2](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP/2) is defined in [RFC 7540](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7540#page-11). [Section 3.5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7540#section-3.5) defines a `PRI` method.

- **PRI**
  In HTTP/2, each endpoint is required to send a connection preface as a final confirmation of the protocol in use and to establish the initial settings for the HTTP/2 connection. … the connection preface starts with the string "PRI *
  HTTP/2.0\r\n\r\nSM\r\n\r\n") …

## Prognostication

> will this ever change?

Not likely.

Given the wide use of Web [RPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call) and [SOAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP), and now the rising popularity of [RESTful](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) services bringing new life to the existing basic verbs, there is little need to devise new verbs at the HTTP level. Where people need their own domain-specific meaningful verbs, they can embed within the message being delivered via HTTP.

I expect we’ll not see more HTTP methods become popular any time soon.

Comment: Regarding HTTP/2:  https://http2.github.io says "HTTP methods, status codes and semantics are the same", so it seems HTTP/2 doesn't introduce any new request methods ("verbs"), though in the spec I do see mention of a PRI method:  "This method is never used by an actual client. This method will appear to be used when an HTTP/1.1 server or intermediary attempts to parse an HTTP/2 connection preface."

Comment: Is WebDAV actually a thing?  I don't see it in practice.  Admittedly my background is with webapps and REST APIs.

Comment: WebDAV is used quite a lot in content management, also (through CalDAV) in calendaring.

Comment: Will there be many more HTTP request methods in the future, or is this process winding down, so that what we have now is basically it?

Comment: @Purplejacket By design, anyone can devise any HTTP methods they want at any time. Any small scale usage by mutual agreement between a small number of parties is inconsequential.  Whether something as significant and wide-spread like WebDAV will come along is difficult to predict. The Registry was last updated 2015-05-19. With [REST](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer) technology having given new life to the existing methods, I expect we’ll not see more methods become popular any time soon.

Comment: Thank you for link to registry. But HTTP 1.0/1.1 distribution is wrong. RFC 1945 declears: `GET`, `HEAD`, `POST`, `PUT`, `DELETE`, `LINK` and `UNLINK` are valid for http 1.0.

Comment: @puchu [RFC 1945](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1945#appendix-D) (HTTP 1.0) declares only the first three: `GET`, `HEAD`, `POST`. The other four are [mentioned only in an appendix](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1945#appendix-D). To quote: “ This appendix documents protocol elements used by some existing HTTP  implementations, but not consistently and correctly across most HTTP/1.0 applications. Implementors should be aware of these features, but cannot rely upon their presence in, or interoperability”

Comment: So we can declear `GET`, `HEAD` and `POST` as strict and others as not strict.

Comment: @puchu No, we can say that three were standardized at that point, and other verbs were experimental. These were the Wild West days of the Web, with all kinds of people trying all kinds of things. Some things stuck and were eventually standardized, while other things fell away.

Answer (score 2):

See the spec:

"Additional methods, outside the scope of this specification, have been standardized for use in HTTP. All such methods ought to be registered within the "Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP) Method Registry" maintained by IANA, as defined in Section 8.1." -- https://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc7231.html#rfc.section.4.1.p.7>

And the [IANA registry](http://www.iana.org/assignments/http-methods/http-methods.xhtml) contains many more.

Comment: I find the IANA registry at http://www.iana.org/assignments/http-methods/http-methods.xhtml -- this mentions 39 methods as of January 2017.  Quite a few of these are from WebDAV or extensions to WebDAV.  I do notice LINK and UNLINK which are related to HTTP 1.1, PRI related to HTTP/2.