# What is rest API methods - COPY, HEAD, OPTIONS, LINK, UNLINK, PURGE, LOCK, UNLOCK, PROPFIND, VIEW

Tags: rest, api, web-services

I am digging into the Rest API methods. In my experience I always use/see four methods in my projects, Methods are - GET, POST,PUT, DELETE

Refer:

[image]

I have try to understand the methods and below is my understanding

> COPY - this will copy an resource, like if I want to copy an object or
>   entity on server I can use it.
>
> HEAD - This method returns no body and provide the activeness of
>   endpoint/resource
>
> OPTIONS - This method basically show which API method is allow on
>   current endpoint, this we can see in header -> ALLOW key
>
> LINK - This method link one object to another object. Basically
>   establish an relationship between two entity/object
>
> UNLINK - This method unlink one object to another object.  remove
>   relationship between objects.
>
> PURGE - No clue
>
> PROPFIND - No clue
>
> VIEW - No clue

Kindly correct me if my understanding is not correct on any above method, please add if I missed anything and kindly explain method like PURGE, PROPFIND , VIEW

Answer (score 4):

REST (the *architectural style*) doesn't specify any methods -- it only says that the interface of resources should be uniform, meaning that all resources share the same understanding of the semantics of the methods.

HTTP defines an application for transferring documents over a network; that specification describes a number of methods that are included in the uniform interface of HTTP resources.
It also defines procedures for extending the vocabulary of methods.

The [Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP) Method Registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/http-methods/http-methods.xhtml) documents the standardized methods, and includes links to the documents in which the semantics of registered methods are defined.

There's a good history of the registered methods [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41411515/54734).

`PURGE` seems to be an unstandardized method discussed in the context of [squid](https://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq/OperatingSquid#How_can_I_purge_an_object_from_my_cache.3F) and [varnish](https://varnish-cache.org/docs/3.0/tutorial/purging.html).

Comment: thats great explanation @voiceOfUnreason and its clear my boarder view for same. can you please also share the working of these verbs .. keeping this question open for verbs descriptions. voting you up .. thanks for sharing this important info