# a form with the PUT method is sent with the GET method

Tags: laravel, forms

I have 2 controller with resource `clients` and `sumsubs`.
being on the `clients.show` route I created a form that I would like to send to the `sumsubs.update` endpoint but it does not work; the form still contacts `sumsubs.show`

[here are the routes that I have defined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZUkt.png)

here is the form

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" class="form-horizontal" name='recheck' method="PUT" action="{{ route('sumsubs.update', $client->id) }}">

      @csrf

      <div class="form-group row">
          <div class="col-sm-10">
               <input type="number" class="form-control" id="candidat" name="candidat" value="{{ $client->id }}" hidden required>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success float-right"> {{ __('Recheck') }} </button>
      </div>
</form>
```

the following is my `sumbsubs controller`

```
public function show($id)
{
  return 'not ok';
}


public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
        return 'ok ';
}
```

[this is what i get when i submit the form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oHQJ6.png)

I would like to know where is my mistake

I read the laravel documentation for form submission and tried with url and route methods but I still get the same result

Answer (score 2):

You have to use [method spoofing](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#form-method-spoofing).
Change your method in form tag to `Post`:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" class="form-horizontal" name='recheck' method="POST" action="{{ route('sumsubs.update', $client->id) }}">
```

and add this after `@csrf`:

```
@method('PUT')
```

Comment: to add explanation above: method spoofing exists solely for the fact [html form method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#attr-method) only support either http method `post` or `get` as per http 1.0 standard. the others are added at [later standards](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41411515).